# Program does not proceed - OpenCV related

Tags: c++, opencv

I finally got OpenCV to work but I encountered a problem where my program does not proceed (no outcome). The outcome of the program should be an image in a new window. Snippet:

```
#include <opencv2/core/core.hpp>
#include <opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp>
#include <iostream>

using namespace cv;
using namespace std;

int main( int argc, char** argv )
{
  if( argc != 2)
{
  cout <<" Usage: display_image ImageToLoadAndDisplay" << endl;
  return -1;
}

   Mat image;
   image = imread(argv[1], IMREAD_COLOR); // Read the file

if(! image.data ) // Check for invalid input
{
    cout << "Could not open or find the image" << std::endl ;
    return -1;
}

   namedWindow( "Display window", WINDOW_AUTOSIZE ); // Create a window for display.
   imshow( "Display window", image ); // Show our image inside it.

   waitKey(0); // Wait for a keystroke in the window
   return 0;
}
```

Point is, program builds successfully but when I debug it, nothing happens. I tried to Start Without Debugging (ctrl+F5, I am using MSVisual2012) and what popped up is:
[image]

How can I fix this? Is it related to bad library linking?

Answer (score 0):

The output is "Usage: display_image ImageToLoadAndDisplay", which means the program didn't get the filename. You can:

1. `image = imread("C:\myfile.jpg", IMREAD_COLOR);` (and remove the previous lines)
2. open terminal, `cd` to the executable dir  and run `yourprogram.exe myfile.jpg`
3. set command arguments in visual studio.

Comment: I used first option:  `image = imread("C:\\Users\\Lisek\\Documents\\Visual Studio 2012\\Projects\\ConsoleApplication1\\opencv-logo.png", IMREAD_COLOR);` and removed the lines before `Mat image;` but now I get `Could not open or find the image`...

Comment: weird. I just tested your program with: `image = imread("C:\\opencv\\samples\\c\\box.png");` and it works fine.

Comment: Do I need OpenCV on the C:\\ partition? I do not think so but still

Comment: The location of the file does not matter. Note that I didn't pass `IMREAD_COLOR` to `imread` because it wont compile on my machine. so I found another post regarding `IMREAD_COLOR`: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21583584/imread-color-underlined-red  , not sure if there's a bug in that version.